Prove roots of a quadratic are real given another quadratic with real roots
If the expression $x^2+ bx + c = 0$ has real roots, show that the roots of $x^2 + bx + c + c(x+a)(2x+b) = 0$ are real for every $a\in \mathbb{R} $
My work:
$$ x^2 + bx + c + c(x+a)(2x+b) = (2c + 1)x^2 + (b + bc + 2ca) x + (c + abc)$$
$$ D = (b+bc+2ca)^2 -4(2c+1)(c+abc) $$
$$ = b^2+b^2c^2+4a^2c^2+2b^2c+4abc^2+4abc - ( 8abc^2 +8c^2+4abc+4c)$$
$$=b^2+b^2c^2+4a^2c^2 + 2b^2c-4abc^2-8c^2-4c$$
For real roots: $D \geq 0$. From the first quadratic
$$ b^2 - 4c \geq 0$$
Since $b^2c^2$ and $4a^2c^2$ are squares and therefore must be $ \geq 0$.
$$ \implies b^2 + b^2c^2 + 4a^2c^2 - 4c \geq 0$$
How do I proceed after this to prove $b^2+b^2c^2+4a^2c^2 + 2b^2c-4abc^2-8c^2-4c \geq 0$?  I tried factorising $ 2b^2c-4abc^2-8c^2$ to show that adding it to the inequality still preserves it but was unsuccessful.
I am aware this is the same question - Prove that the roots of $g(x)$ are also real , but the author has forgotten that the constant term in $g(x)$ is not merely $abc$ but in fact $abc + c$, thereby getting the wrong discriminant and leading others to believe the question is wrong. Any hints would be great!

You cannot say $b^2c^2,4a^2c^2\ge0$ so we ignore them, because sometime they are use to balance away the negative terms behind.

Oh, I overlooked that

Note the question you linked to doesn't have the $+c$ term in its second quadratic, which is why the constant term in $g(x)$ is $abc$, not $abc + c$ as it is in yours. FYI, using an Approach0 search, two other questions asking about the same problem as the one you linked to are Proving roots will be real and Showing that the roots of the quadratic are real.

Hey, I didn't know about Approacho, is it a method to find similar questions on stackexchange? As far as I checked on this interface, I couldn't find those questions, but they are there on Approacho?

@Illusioner_ Approach0 is an external tool to find questions with similar mathematical expressions, so it often works better than the internal StackExchange search, and even various general search engines (e.g., Google, Bing, etc.). Currently, it has only indexed questions from this site, i.e., Math StackExchange (but not the other math site here, i.e., MathOverflow), and also Art of Problem Solving, but I only ever recall seeing questions from their Community section. For more information about Approach0, see this ...

@Illusioner_ (cont.) answer. Note the other answers there provide additional helpful searching tips.

Continuing from your last line of the work with the full discriminant expression, we get
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
& \color{blue}{b^2} + \color{green}{b^2c^2 + 4a^2c^2} + \color{red}{2b^2c} - \color{green}{4abc^2} - \color{red}{8c^2} - \color{blue}{4c} \\
& = (\color{blue}{b^2 - 4c}) + (\color{green}{b^2c^2 + 4a^2c^2 - 4abc^2}) + (\color{red}{2b^2c - 8c^2}) \\
& = (b^2 - 4c) + c^2(b^2 - 4ab + 4a^2) + 2c(b^2 - 4c) \\
& = (b^2 - 4c) + c^2(b - 2a)^2 + 2c(b^2 - 4c) \\
& = (1 + 2c)(b^2 - 4c) + c^2(b - 2a)^2
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
However, this shows that the question's premise, with the information provided, is not necessarily always correct. In particular, with $a = \frac{b}{2}$, the second term is $0$ so, if $c \lt -\frac{1}{2} \;\to\; 1 + 2c \lt 0$, then if $b^2 - 4c \gt 0$, the first term above is negative. Thus, the discriminant of the second quadratic polynomial is negative, which means this doesn't have real roots.

I think this is why I couldn't solve the question. I was trying to factor all the terms as squares to show they were positive, but I overlooked the possibility of the question being wrong

Actually I do not think that this statement holds. Consider $c=-\dfrac{1}{2}$, $b=2$, then the equation $x^2+2x-0.5=0$ has real roots. Now pick $a=1$. Then the equation becomes $$x^2+2x-0.5-0.5(x+1)(2x+2)\equiv-1.5$$
which is always negative, so this cannot have real zeros.
The reason of picking this choice is because at $c=-0.5$, the required equation fails to become quadratic, now we pick $a$ such that the coefficient of $x$ is zero, then it cannot have real soln.

It could be argued that this does not answer the question, because it is reasonable to presume that the problem composer intended that the expression $$x^2 + bx + c + c(x+a)(2x+b)$$ does represent a quadratic.  So, the problem composer presumably intended that the coefficient of $~x^2~$ in the above expression is not equal to $~0.$  I emphasize that this viewpoint is arguable; it could also be argued that your analysis is perfectly valid.

Oh what I mean is like he should impose other condition to ensure this at least can be indeed a quadratic, just the someone answer it on his linked question.

Yes, but it is not that unusual for the problem composer to fail to consider that the expression might not represent a quadratic.  It is a natural mistake to make.

yah I should delete this soon, thanks for noticing

Oh yes, that wasn't an included condition in my question, thanks for pointing it out however.

The OP correctly derived the following expression for the discrimant $D$:
$$D = b^2 +4a^2c^2 + b^2c^2 +2b^2c - 4abc^2 -8c^2 - 4c$$
To obtain the minimum of $D$ with respect to the variable $a$, we differentiate and set the result equal to zero.
$$0 = \frac {dD}{da} = 8ac^2 - 4bc^2$$
It follows that the minimum is found for $a = b/2$. Substitute this result in $D$. Some cancellation of terms takes places, and we obtain:
$$D = b^2 +2b^2c - 8c^2-4c = (b^2-4c)(1 + 2c)$$
Since $b^2 - 4c \ge 0$, we see that $D \ge 0$ is only true for all values of $a$ when $1+2c \ge 0$ or $b^2-4c = 0$.
